# Remote desktop connection to Ubuntu 20.4 using vino (from osx)

Tags: ssh, 20.04, vino

I am trying to connect to remote Ubuntu 20.04 machine. For the installation/configuration I can only use ssh.

I have enabled screen sharing, and started the vino service through ssh via :
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server

When I connect (on osx side i am using vnc viewer), I get blank black screen. It seems to be known gnome bug (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399979). For that reason I installed gnome-flashback-metacity.

I guess just installing is not enough, new desktop env should also be started. How can I do that through ssh? Restarting the computer doesnt seem to help. Since I dont have physical access to the computer I am not able to login to the computer by selecting new gnome-flashback version.

The default desktop environment is supposed to be set somwehere in cd /var/lib/AccountsService/users, but I am not able to cd into this folder (permission denied), although I am in the sudo group.
How can I the default desktop environment to gnome-flashback through ssh?

I am also not sure if I understand everything correctly. If I log to remote computer through ssh, after the computer was restarted, does this mean that the desktop environment is running?
I am confused because my $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP and $GDMSESSION are empty ..